# How do i work out the nearest resolution with 16:9 aspect ratio. python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a project I am working on I need to make a function that takes an input of height and width and outputs the nearest height and width that have a ratio of 16:9

here is what i have got so far

```
def image_to_ratio(h, w):
    if width % 16 < height % 9:
        h -= (h % 9)
    else:
        w -= (w% 9)
    return h, w
```

input:
    1920, 1200

output of my function:
    1920, 1197

Comment: have you made some attempt?

Comment: yeah i have but it is no where close to working.

Comment: well what have you tried, what does it output, and what were you actually expecting it to output(ie how do you know its no where close to working)? ...

Comment: Firstly find out how much the width should be increased in order to have 16:9 using a loop, then find out how much the height should be increased. Then compare both of them, which is lesser, and show the output

Comment: whoah no need for a loop ... (also @hananf edit the question with your attempt, and what it outputs(that is wrong))

Comment: Do you need both simply to be smaller than the given values?

Comment: I have changed the function to what I have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
from __future__ import division  # needed in Python2 only

def image_to_ratio(w, h):
    if (w / h) < (16 / 9):
        w = (w // 16) * 16
        h = (w // 16) * 9
    else: 
        h = (h // 9) * 9
        w = (h // 9) * 16
    return w, h 

>>> image_to_ratio(1920, 1200)
(1920, 1080)
```

That same logic can be condensed into:

```
def image_to_ratio(w, h):
    base = w//16 if w/h < 16/9 else h//9
    return base * 16, base * 9
```

Comment: First code isn't working as expected, the output is `2128, 1197`

Comment: @Zlytherin try py3 (they changed how division works)

Comment: @schwobaseggl, Ohh damm, I need some sleep!! I'm just going mad, Now I can understand

Comment: @Zlytherin Go to bed, dangnabbit! :D

Comment: @schwobaseggl, Going to bed.. ;) Your answer should be the accepted one, upvoted

Answer (score 1):

second shortest version of @schwobaseggl's answer:

```
def image_to_ratio(h, w):
    if (w/h) < (16/9):h,w=16*(h//16),9*(h//16)
    else:h,w=16*(h//9),9*(h//9)
    return h,w
```

And now:

```
print(image_to_ratio(1920, 1200))
```

Is:

```
(1920, 1080)
```